# JavaScript In KML Ignored By Google Earth Plugin

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I've created a simple KML file that works in the standalone Google Earth client, but won't work at all in the Google Earth Plugin (regardless of browser):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Folder>
        <name>South Florida</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Document>
            <name>Miami</name>
            <Style id="miami_style">
                <IconStyle>
                    <Icon>
                        <href>http://i.imgur.com/CNrRU.gif</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
                <BalloonStyle>
                    <text><![CDATA[<font face="Arial">$[description]</font>]]></text>
                </BalloonStyle>
            </Style>
            <Folder>
                <name>Miami</name>
                <open>1</open>
                <Placemark id="Miami">
                    <name>Miami</name>
                    <description><![CDATA[
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function hideImage() {
                                var image = document.getElementById("image");
                                image.style.opacity = 0;
                                image.style.MozOpacity = 0;
                                image.style.KhtmlOpacity = 0;
                                image.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
                            }
                        </script>
                        <button id='clicker' onclick='hideImage();'>Click Me</button>
                        <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/4rhT7.png">
                    ]]></description>
                    <styleUrl>#miami_style</styleUrl>
                    <Point>
                        <coordinates>-80.22643611111111,25.788952777777777,0</coordinates>
                    </Point>
                </Placemark>
            </Folder>
        </Document>
    </Folder>
</kml>
```

Basically, I have an image that displays by default, and I want to make it go away when I click the button. Eventually, I want to be able to toggle images by clicking, but I figure this needs to work first in order to get to that step.

This works perfectly fine in standalone Google Earth, but doesn't work in the Google Earth Plugin.

Oddly, this also works in the Google Earth Plugin if I run it in a JavaScript console *after* the balloon is already displayed. It just doesn't acknowledge the code already in the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Earth API strips out any javascript in a Balloon description for security purposes.  A common workaround is to listen for a click event on your placemark (or a balloonopening event more generally) and then recreate an HtmlDivBalloon programmatically with the full content.  For more details check out http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/balloons.html#getballoonhtmlunsafe

Comment: Is this something that can be done from within a KML? I need this to work without modifying code on the server, if at all possible.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out after scrolling up on that page, that all "description" content gets scrubbed. The event to generate a balloon (or the 'click' event) must be overridden server-side in order to get this to work. *sigh*

http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/balloons.html#scrubbing

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, and have been looking around for a solution. I have found this answer, which I have yet to try myself, but it may be useful to you:

http://markmail.org/message/ivlw7jv3u5nxwkde

I hope so - do share any success you have!

Comment: Thanks. Yea I just found out about the whole "scrubbing" thing: http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/balloons.html#scrubbing

Answer (score 0):

A simple JavaScript code (even simple jQuery) can be inputted into  or  and it will work. However in the Google Earth environment only. After depreciation of the Google Earth API we cannot really use the JS in  .kml file outside the Google Earth.
Read more about it here:
http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/content-management-in-kml-files/

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful with some more details. Can you flesh out your explanation, please? You say "A simple JavaScript code (even simple jQuery)". Can you show what that would look like?

Comment: OK, telling a simple JavaScript code I meant: clock, twinkling text, temperature converter of the filterable table. In general stuff like this.